# Why is Mustafar different in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Episode 3: Revenge of the Sith*, Mustafar is a volcanic planet filled with lava.

[image]

While in *Rogue One*, the skies are different and the lava is not that scattered anymore.

[image]

**Is there any information on why Mustafar is different in these two films?**

Comment: I personally think it's just two parts of same planet. One in Revenge of the Sith was some sort of manufacturing factory(or something), so it could be placed near vulcanos to harvest something(heat or some minerals, or something else). Vaders place is a large construction, so may need more stable grounding, thus it is placed on more solid part of the planet.

Comment: To add to @MrHutnik’s comment, It might be said that the scenes pictured are in opposite hemispheres; For example- ROTS is set in the north (volcanic and hot) while Vader’s retreat (as seen in Rogue One) is located in the cooler south.

Comment: So you mean you expect that all Star Wars planets are single-biome planets?

Comment: what part of the castle being built over a giant lava river seems different?

Comment: Isn’t this sort of akin to asking why shots of the Greenland ice sheet and the Brazilian rain forest look so different? I don’t remember the details in either film, but do we ever see more than localised shots, to make us believe that those shots are representative of the entire planet?

Comment: To comment on the comments: In the real universe, planets have different climate zones. Even Mars has polar ice caps, deserts around the equator and even a giant (dead) volcano, far larger than any on Earth. However, in the Star Wars universe, planets tend to have just a simple biome and climate zone: The desert planet Tatooine, the ice planet Hith, the forest moon of Endor, the swamp planet Dagobah, etc. In this context, it is fair to ask why Mustafar looks different in the two movies.

Comment: Even so, an entirely volcanic planet is bound to have areas with more or less volcanic activity.

Comment: Maybe in those 2 decades that have passed the Empire has started to deplete the resources and climate change happened?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Because in *Episode 3*, we are seeing a mining facility, and in *Rogue One* we are seeing a residence.

Since Mustafarian mining involves extracting minerals from the lava, it needs to be near an open and active lava flow.

> The lava on Mustafar wasn't as hot as normal lava, this was due to **unusual mineral allotropes that are molten** at lower temperatures.
>
> *[...]*
>
> The planet's native Mustafarian species lived in underground caves created by lava fleas as they ate through the planet's crust, and made their armor from the heat-resistant shells of the creatures. Only venturing up to the surface in order to collect **valuable minerals from the lava flows**.
> <sub>[Mustafar - Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mustafar)</sub>

<sup>*(emphasise mine)*</sup>

Vader's castle, on the other hand, has no such requirements.

> Darth Vader constructed his own castle, a testament to his might, at the site of his greatest defeat: the fiery lava-world, Mustafar. The location and design of the castle came as much from the dark side as it did from Vader's personal history, however; the complex sits atop an ancient Sith cave, and the tuning towers serve as a conduit for the dark side of the Force.
> <sub>[Darth Vader - Star Wars Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/darth-vader)</sub>

Even though it says the castle was built "at the site of his greatest defeat", it is important to note that it means the planet, not literally the lava bank on which he lost 3 limbs.